# How to use the Watson Text2Speech REST API in a cordova App?

Tags: javascript, rest, cordova, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

There are many samples: How to use Watson Services in Node.JS, but if you using the REST API with HTTP calls I run into problems with the authorization.

The [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/getting_started/gs-tokens.shtml) of the API  tells about the commandline **curl** interface,
but there is no concrete sample for **HTTP calls** for web or Hybrid Applications **using javascript**.

In my situation I want to use the Watson Text2Speech in a cordova Mobile APP, for this I going to build a factory.

The http calls I use do work for other APIs, **but what I am doing wrong here?**
*Any missing format?*

Can anyone help?

Which looks like this:

```
.factory('GetSpeech', ['$http','$cordovaDialogs','$cordovaMedia','Base64', function($http,
                                                                                    $cordovaDialogs,
                                                                                    $cordovaMedia,
                                                                                    Base64){
  // http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/media/
  // https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/input.shtml
  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-speech-recognition-feat-siri
  var watson_url = "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize";
  var watson_token_url = "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api";
  var watson_token = "";
  var username='YOUR_KEY';
  var password='YOUR_PW';
  var authdata = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);
  console.log(">>> Watson - authdata: ",authdata);
  var the_get_header = "{'Authorization':'"+ authdata +"','Content-Type':'application/json'}";

  var message = "";

  var getSpeech_innner = function (){ $http({method: 'GET',
                                            url:  watson_token_url,
                                            headers: the_get_header
                                       }).then( function successCallback(response) {
                                           console.log(">>> GetToken  Success:",response);
                                           watson_token=response;
                                           var the_post_header = "{'X-Watson-Authorization-Token':'"+ watson_token +"','Content-Type':'application/json','Accept':'audio/wav'}";
                                           var the_post_text = JSON.stringify({ "text":"This is the first sentence of the paragraph. Here is another sentence. Finally, this is the last sentence."
                                                                              });
                                           $http({
                                              method: 'POST',
                                              url: watson_url,
                                              headers: the_post_header,
                                              data: the_post_text
                                            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                                                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                                                // when the response is available
                                                console.log(">>> GetSpeech Success:",response);
                                                message = "Success: " + response;
                                                alert(message);
                                                return true;
                                                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                                                  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                                                  // or server returns response with an error status.
                                                  console.log(">>> GetSpeech  Error:",response);
                                                  message = "Error: " + response;
                                                  alert(message);
                                                  return false;
                                                })
                                            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                                               console.log(">>> GetToken  Error:",response);
                                            });
                                      };
  return {
    getSpeech :  getSpeech_innner
  };

}])
```

[image]

*NOTE:* By the way in the postman the HTTP calls working. The **GET Token** and the **POST synthesize**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I my situation I wanted to get a token directly from the **service broker**.

At the current situation it seems for the communication with the *text2speech service* , I need a extra **server app**, for example running on **Node.JS Server**, which provides the **token** for the **cordova app** client.

Sample code for the **server token app** is available in the documentation.

This is documented in the chapter programming models in topic using token.
[Watson Documentation Link](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/getting_started/gs-develop.shtml)

This is related to the developing models for the watson services. 
The reason is that Postman and CURL calls are allowed and other request by Web or Mobile Applications are not valid Origins.

So you can **not** use the REST API directly, from the Mobile Application or Web Application. The same situation, is by using the Watson IoT. 
This is the reason why I used a node framework in a Angular Web App by using Browserify [Sample GitHub Project: browserfied-ibmiotf-webapplication](https://github.com/thomassuedbroecker/browserfied-ibmiotf-webapplication)

For a better understanding one picture from the Watson API documentation.
This is documented in the chapter programming models in topic using token.
[Watson Documentation Link](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/getting_started/gs-develop.shtml)

[image]

**@Thanks** to Rene and Andrew pointing me in this direction.

Now I have a working cordova app with Text2Speech.
I do not use the **token** in this sample, the speech is provided directly from the Node.JS server to the Mobile App.

**@Thanks** to Andrii, providing some code to do this.

**Node.JS Server:**

```
app.get('/getText2SpeechOutput', function (req, res) {
    console.log(' -> text function called');

    console.log('     calling watson to synthesize -> ', req.header('synthesize-text'));

    var text_to_speech_l = new Text2speech({
        username: req.header('service-username'),
        password: req.header('service-password'),
    });

    var params = {
        text: req.header('synthesize-text'),
        voice: 'en-US_AllisonVoice',
        accept: 'audio/wav'
    };

    var tempaudio = text_to_speech_l.synthesize(params);
    console.log('     response received from Watson');
    var reader = new wav.Reader();

    reader.on('format', function (format) {

        console.log('     file read success');
        var writer = new wav.FileWriter('output.wav', {
                channels: 1,
                sampleRate: 22050,
                bitDepth: 16
            });

        reader.pipe(writer);

        console.log('     file write success');

        writer.pipe(res)

        console.log(' <- response provided');
    });

    tempaudio.pipe(reader);
})
```

**Cordova App:**

```
 var getSpeech_innner = function (thetext, callback){
                            //const fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                            var headers = {
                              "Authorization": authdata,
                              "Accept": "audio/wav",
                              "synthesize-text": thetext,
                              "service-username": username,
                              "service-password": password
                            };

                            var options = {
                              headers: headers,
                              replace: true
                            };

                            $cordovaFileTransfer.download(get_speech_url , cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'speech.wav', options, true).then(
                              function (FileEntry) {
                                console.debug('>>> Success', FileEntry);
                                var filePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'speech.wav';
                                callback(filePath);
                              },
                              function (error) {
                                console.debug('>>> download failure', error);
                                callback(error);
                              });
                        };
```

Comment: The token actually comes from the DataPower Edge Router (blue step 3), but you've got the right idea here - client-side usage still requires a server to generate tokens.

Comment: @Thomas.Thanks this is very helpful the node js one...Im getting response as RIFF **** in some unreadable format in postman..how can make that  download that when we trigger that call from postman

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the same on a similar way:

```
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: tts_url,
    headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'access-control-allow-headers, Authorization',
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Basic <base64(uid:password)>',
          'Accept': 'audio/wav'
          },
    data: {'\"text\"': '\"hello world\"' },
    output: 'hello_world.wav'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log(">>> Success:",response.status);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log(">>> Error:", response.status);
  });
```

I'll get this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize.
>   (Reason: missing token 'access-control-allow-headers' in CORS header
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).

The behavior is the same, when I remove the "access-control-allow-headers" entry in the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header...

Running the same in postman works fine.

**How do I allow my cordova app to call a remote resource?**

Comment: Access-Controll-* headers belong on the response, not the request.

Comment: The reason for the CORS issue is that you are in development mode. Testing directly on the device should work. There are numerous ways to cope with that, e.g. set up a proxy in ionic, disable cors in your browser. This is a good reference: http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: @Sebstian Please see https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/getting_started/gs-develop.shtml 

I would say this depends on the developing models inside for the watson services. The reason is that Postman and CURL calls are allowed and other request by Web or Mobile Applications not.

So you can not use the REST API directly, from the Mobile Application or Web Application. The same situation, is by using the Watson IoT.
This is the reason why I used a node framework in a Angular Web App https://github.com/thomassuedbroecker/browserfied-ibmiotf-webapplication.

Answer (score 1):

Have you whitelisted the `stream.watsonplatform.net` origin in your Cordova application?  It looks to me like the domain is being blocked.  Details on whitelisting here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/

Comment: This is my config.xml entry and   <access origin="*" /> allows all, so `stream.watsonplatform.net` or `*.watsonplatform.net` should not be a problem :thinking_face::disappointed:

Extract config.xml
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />